# Node.JS sequelizejs many to many

Tags: database, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm working on a web site where users can have a project, and for each project they have, they are assigned a certain role. Here is the schema

[image: Schema]

How I can make it with the model of squelize (Or maybe it's better to don't use an ORM (it's what I'm thinking right now..))

Here you can see a part of my model :

```
//Users
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        // ******** //
    }, {
        tableName: 'users',
        freezeTableName: true
    });
};

//Projects
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('Project', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'projects',
        freezeTableName: true
    });
};

//ProjectRole :
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('ProjectRole', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'projects_roles',
        freezeTableName: true
    });
};


//user has projects :
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    return sequelize.define('UserProject', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

    }, {
        tableName: 'users_has_projects',
        freezeTableName: true
    });

};
```

Comment: Sooo.... what's the question?

Comment: Well true my question isn't clear, my question would be : How can I do the "link" between those 3 table in sequelize and how to query those data properly with sequelize